# Общий шаблон для jsp

Tags: html, jsp

Как можно сделать общий шаблон для всех jsp файлов где будет весь дизайн сайта, и мог его импортировать.

Comment: вы через IDE работаетe?

Comment: Да, через Intellije Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблонизаторов есть несколько для jsp, наверное самые популярные:

[Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/)

[Struts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts)

Comment: Есть ли такая возможность просто хранить jsp с дизайном и его импориртировать в каждый jsp возможно ли так

Comment: Можно просто через jsp:include нужную jsp с дизайном подключать.

Comment: и это будет правильным?

Comment: Послений вопросу нужно как-то подругому сформулировать. Кто правила определяет?
Это будет валидный jsp

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в настройки `IDEA` в поиске напишите `File and Code templates` потом нажмите на кнопку `other` и перейдите в вкладку `WEB` там нажмите на `JSP`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нельзя ли как то в одном файле, что бы если я менял дизайн то он везде менялся, там будет храниться дизайн всего сайта