# Как правильно вынести отдельные элементы JSP страницы?

Tags: html5, java-ee, jsp, шаблоны

Подскажите пожалуйста как вынести отдельные статические `.jsp` элементы которые повторяются во всех страницах допустим шапку, меню, футер и т.п. которые повторяются, и чтоб не приходилось заново их писать, а просто вызывать там где мне нужно?

Comment: Чегоо? Что имеется ввиду 'отдельный элемент' ?

Comment: У меня на странице есть меню которое дублироваться будет для многих страниц. Сейчас я его копирую на все страницы это не удобно хочу вынести его отдельно и вставлять в нужные страницы.!))))

Comment: Аааа это) Понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы каждый раз не повторять ваше меню, вам нужно создать отдельный `.jsp` файл где будет находится допустим это будет `menu.jsp`, а вызывать его такой командой в другом `.jsp` файле вставив в нужное место написав такую простенькую строку

```
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
```

Вот небольшой пример:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <!--head-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ include file="_menu.jsp" %>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Записывать нужно с <meta> <script> все как обычно?

Comment: @Verlamov Я добавил маленький пример

Comment: @KryTer_NexTза пример спасибо большое! делал как в примере вашем вылетает ошибка 500
https://github.com/ArtyrGetman/platfor_sport/tree/verlamov/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages

Comment: @Verlamov Хмм странно... У меня все нормально было, может проблема скорее всего в 'шаблоне' в котором вы вызываете?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте шаблоны (templates) для JSP.

Посмотрите Struts2(Tiles) Pug(Jade) для HTML(если нужно). Tapestry может пригодиться.

Вот несколько ссылок для чтения:

[Общий шаблон для jsp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456171/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-jsp)

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076174/java-web-development/jsp-templates.html

http://www.java2ee.ru/frameworks/struts2/tiles.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier

http://struts.apache.org/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html

http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/1447551/An-Introduction-to-JSP-Standard-Template-Library-JSTL.htm